# Octave Installation Failing on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: qt, octave, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install octave through brew on mac (10.10.5 Yosemite). The command used is `brew install octave` . While installing, the process tries to install qt (version 4.8.7) which is essentially failing with the below error

> Error : 'File already exists. /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7'.

When I check the file at this particular location, I don`t see any such directory, though the directory does appear and is created during the installation (probably getting removed later when the task fails). 
Could someone please point out what I need to do exactly? Is Qt really required for Octave installation? If not then any way to skip it?

Comment: Did you tried to ask there? - https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/support.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. No I havent but would try now.

Comment: Its resolved now :).  I followed the steps from here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29989 comment by mysterycommand to restore my OS X essentials back to its original and then run brew command and it worked fine,